# What is the difference between 3 times Edo Tensei have been used?

Tags: naruto

We have seen this jutsu performed three times during OG Naruto and Shippuden.

- Orochimaru used Tobirama and Hashirama vs Hiruzen
- Kabuto uses an army of Edo Tensei
- Orochimaru Edo Tensei 4 hokages

Why the first edo tensei done by Orochimaru was considered weak?
Also, he used White Zetsu for 4 hokages while it is said it needs a living sacrifice.

Comment: Related: [How could Madara free himself from the Impure World Resurrection technique, while Tobirama can't?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3027/310)

Comment: "Also, he used White Zetsu for 4 hokages while it is said it needs a living sacrifice." I don't see a reason why White Zetsu should not count as "living", but even if I saw one, I can't argue with the author.